# Starting a conversation with Microsoft bot builder and microsoft bot framework

Tags: bots, botframework

I tried to have my bot start a conversation with the user but I don't know where in the code I should send the message from. The documentation for starting a convo is here, but it's not super helpful: http://docs.botframework.com/connector/new-conversations/#navtitle. I also tried replying in the HandleSystemMessages (which works with the emulator if I change the message type) but it still won't send the first message.

I'm using Microsoft Bot Connector and C#.

// Idk how to do syntax highlighting in stackoverflow
// This is my code from the MessageController Class

```
public async Task<Message> Post([FromBody]Message message)
    {
        if (message.Type == "Message")
        {
            return message.CreateReplyMessage($"You said:{message.Text}");
        }
        else
        {
            return HandleSystemMessage(message);
        }
    }
```

Comment: Did you manage to find a solution to this? I am also struggling with this exact same problem. Cannot figure it out. The developer documentation is useless. Very unhelpful.

Answer (score 2):

I spent a lot of time researching this issue. As a result, I managed to initiate sending a message on behalf of the bot. My example sends a message to a group conversation. The code below - is rough draft but it works:

```cs
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var connector = new ConnectorClient(new Uri("https://skype.botframework.com"));
        var conversationId = "19:ConversationAccountId@thread.skype";
        var conversation = new ConversationAccount(true, conversationId);
        var botAccount = new ChannelAccount("28:74a05skypeBotChannelAccountId", "your bot name");

        IMessageActivity message = Activity.CreateMessageActivity();
        message.From = botAccount;
        message.Conversation = conversation;
        message.ChannelId = "skype";
        message.Text = "some text";
        message.Locale = "en-En";
        connector.Conversations.SendToConversation((Activity)message);
    }
}
```

Comment: I used this document: https://docs.botframework.com/en-us/csharp/builder/sdkreference/routing.html#conversation

Comment: Can you please show us where to implement this code? How can we do it if we aren't using Skype? You've linked the guy to the same page he said he found unhelpful. Can you maybe elaborate on your answer please? I assume he hasn't marked it correct as he probably never managed to figure it out.

Comment: I stopped work on this project. I had task to initialize conversation in direction from my Skype Bot to any known Skype contact. Code above helped to solve my task. What is mean "if we aren't using Skype"? You can use any Channel supported by botframework, for example Facebook, email, slack etc.

Comment: For example you can use code above inside console application or another place. I used it inside scheduler implemented as console application.

Comment: For starting work you need register own Microsoft bot and replace  botAccount variable with it. Also you need previously stored  information about your contacts (conversationId) and use any stored conversationId instead "19:ConversationAccountId@thread.skype"

Comment: I am making my bot as a console application at the minute, and I am unsure what Class to implement this in..

If I am using console app how can I make the bot speak first instead of the user speaking first to trigger the MessageController?

Comment: Can you maybe edit your answer to show full class code or maybe just more code?

Comment: A minute ago, this code has been successfully completed and sent me a message. message: http://imgur.com/a/0TAYT